# Orthogonal Matrix with respect to different inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

From what I understand, an orthogonal matrix is one that satisfies $A\cdot A^t = I_n$. In such case, from what I saw online, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\;\left\Vert Ax \right\Vert =\left\Vert x \right\Vert $.

I took this to the test and looked at the orthogonal matrix $$V = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
0 & \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

(and you may check that this indeed is an orthogonal matrix that satisfies $V\cdot V^t = I_n$)

and looked at $$V\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ \:1\\ \:1\end{matrix}\right) =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}-2\sqrt{3}}{6}\\ \frac{3\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}+2\sqrt{3}}{6}\\ \frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}$$

and obviously with respect to the norm $\left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert _\infty = \max\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ we get that $\left\Vert Vx \right\Vert \neq\left\Vert x \right\Vert $.

I assume, therefore, that this property only applies to the standard inner product (dot product).

My question is, is there a definition $\star$ for orthogonal matrices with respect to different inner products (or different norms)? will there be other equivalent definitions similar to $A\cdot A^t = I_n$?

$\star$ I know I can define such matrices by myself, but I'd like to know if such theory has been developed already and what can be said about it, mainly with respect to properties similar to $A\cdot A^t = I_n$.

Also, I do know that for general linear transformation there are orthogonal operators with respect to general inner products, but when converting those to matrices, the lengths seem to be preserved with respect to the inner product.

Comment: for an inner product with Hessian matrix $H,$   an automorphism $A$   satisfies $A H A^t = H$

Comment: @WillJagy What does Hessian matrix mean in this context? So such "A" is called an automorphism? Google can't find any good results on "automorphism matrix"

Answer (score 0):

This is very wrong. The definition of real orthogonal matrix is $A^TA=I$, not $AA^T=I$. Although either one implies the other, only the former correctly reflects what we want, namely, $\|Ax\|_2=\|x\|_2$. As we shall see below, the former condition also gives a correct generalisation when other inner products are involved.

The definition of orthogonal matrix you saw online ($\|Ax\|_2=\|x\|_2$) basically says that $A$ preserves the Euclidean norm. A better and equivalent definition is that $A$ preserves the usual dot product. That is, $(Ax,Ay)=(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the dot product. With this definition, we say that $A$ is orthogonal with respect to an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ if it preserves this inner product, that is, if $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle$ is identically equal to $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Owing to the [polarisation identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), $A$ preserves an inner product if and only if $A$ preserves the norm induced by this inner product. So, you may also take $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ (where $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$) as a definition, but it is easier to work with the inner-product than to work with norm.

Every inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ is induced by some symmetric positive definite matrix $P$, so that the inner product between two vectors $x$ and $y$ is given by $\langle x,y\rangle_P=(Px,y)$. If $A$ is orthogonal with respect to this inner product, i.e., if $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle_P\equiv\langle x,y\rangle_P$, we say that $A$ is $P$-orthogonal. In this case, $A$ is clearly nonsingular. Furthermore, since
$$
(Px,y)
\equiv\langle x,y\rangle_P
\equiv\langle Ax,Ay\rangle_P
\equiv(PAx,Ay)
\equiv(A^TPAx,y),
$$
we may characterise a $P$-orthogonal matrix as a matrix $A$ that satisfies the condition
$$
A^TPA=P.
$$
The usual definition $A^TA=I$ when $P=I$ is clearly included as a special case.

Note the the $A^T$ in the above is the usual matrix transpose of $A$. The “$P$-transpose” of $A$, i.e., the transpose of $A$ with respect to the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_P$, is the matrix $B$ characterised by $\langle Ax,y\rangle_P\equiv\langle x,By\rangle_P$. If we put $v=A^{-1}y$, we obtain $\langle x,v\rangle_P\equiv\langle Ax,Av\rangle_P\equiv\langle x,BAv\rangle_P$. Therefore $BA=I$, i.e., $B=A^{-1}$. In other words, regardless of $P$, the $P$-transpose of a $P$-orthogonal matrix $A$ is always identical to $A^{-1}$. This is a generalisation of the usual case where $P=I$ and $A^T=A^{-1}$.